# Can't read property showImagePicker of undefined in react native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have tired with this issue

1. npm install react-native-image-picker@latest --save
2. react-native link react-native-image-picker

**import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';**

```
const options = {
      quality: 1.0,
      maxWidth: 500,
      maxHeight: 500,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true
      }
    };


    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        console.log('Response = ', response);

        if (response.didCancel) {
          console.log('User cancelled image picker');
        } else if (response.error) {
          console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else if (response.customButton) {
          console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        } else {
          const source = { uri: response.uri };

          // You can also display the image using data:
          // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

          this.setState({
            avatarSource: source,
          });
        }
      });[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should restart the packager , every time you run link command in order to take effect. Just cancel the running packager and run `react-native run-ios` again

Comment: uninstall & unlink  image-picker. and reinstall and relink this. then after 'react-native run-ios'. so still getting this issue, and also one more time Execute link command and 'react-native run-ios'. but issue is not resolve. and in Android it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `react-native-link` it affects 3 files in your android folder, the `build.gradle` file (located android/app), the `settings.gradle` (located android/) and the `MainApplication.java` file (located android/app/src/java).

Normally while linking, the dependencies don't get applied in `build.gradle` at times. Therefore check whether the package (`react-native-image-picker`) is added, if not go ahead and add it as `compile project(':react-native-image-picker')`.

Likewise, check all the other files specified above whether the package is defined.

**This is for android** (I misunderstood the question as i experienced the same issue and fixed it for android)

Comment: in android it's working fine, only getting issue in iOS. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also was dealing with this weird issue for a couple of days, in some threats in Github and some other questions here I could not find a solution that really solved the problem from my side till I found this bizarre but effective one!
Here are the steps I followed:

1.- Open Xcode and from your project directory, go to the folder libraries. After that, go and find `RNImagePicker` and open Products folder.

2.- Go to the Build Phases Tab.

3.- Then **drag and drop** `libRnImagePicker.a` to Link Binary With Libraries. 
[image: This step is the magic one]

This step is the magic one, by doing this a missed link relation in your project is going to be generated by this time your project should look like this:
[image]

4.- Close your project

5.- `Run sudo rm -rf node_modules/.cache`

6.- After this, compile your project either with Xcode or with react-native run-ios
While the compilation happens and the link dependency gets register it will return an error of cycle dependencies (But this is actually good news, we are almost there!)

7.- Open again the route described in step 1 and remove `libRNImagePicker.a` by clicking in the minus buttom.
[image]

8.- Run your project again, and **voila**! The `react-native-image-picker` is working! :)